# Evitar repetir código Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una página en la cual cuando el usuario de click en cualquier opción de un menú me muestre la información del `.html` que el selecciono, dicho menú posee etiquetas `<a>` y con el atributo `href` que posee las etiquetas, con la implementación de Ajax, muestro los `.html` solicitados.

La duda que tengo es que si existe alguna manera de optimizar el código y evitar escribir tanto código Ajax repetido.

- Etiquetas `<a>` y caja donde muestro el `.html` solicitado

```html
    <a  href="ejemplo1">Ejemplo #1</a>

    <a  href="ejemplo1">Ejemplo #2</a>

    <a  href="ejemplo1">Ejemplo #3</a>

    <div id="div_dinamico></div>
```

- Ajax

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    switch(href)
    {

        case 'ejemplo1':
            $.ajax({  
                url: 'ejemplo1.html',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#div_dinamico').html(data); 
                }  
            }); 
            break;

        case 'ejemplo2':
            $.ajax({  
                url: 'ejemplo2.html',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#div_dinamico').html(data); 
                }
            });
            break;

        case 'ejemplo3':
        $.ajax({  
            url: 'ejemplo3.html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#div_dinamico').html(data); 
            }
        });
        break;

        default:
            console.log("Ninguna opcion es valida.");
            break;
    }

});
```

Comment: ya te dieron la respuesta, justo eso te iba a responder ayer.

Comment: Yo no usaría `href` con el valor igual al archivo, el usuario puede hacer `ctrl + click` y abrir el documento en una nueva pestaña. Mi recomendación seria utilizar, por ejemplo, un [`data-atribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos)

Comment: @Marcos tienes razón, leeré el enlace que dejaste y cualquier duda vuelvo a preguntar, gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El `switch` esta de mas solo puedes pasarle href a la url

Ejemplo:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var href = $(this).attr('href');  
    $.ajax({  
        url: href,
        success: function(data) {
          $('#div_dinamico').html(data); 
        }  
    });                
});
```

Comment: En principio la respuesta es correcta, pero me parece que sería `url: href + '.html',`. De todas formas deberías preguntar si es realmente necesario o no validar que sea `ejemplo1, ejemplo2, etc` y evitar el hacer el ajax en caso contrario

Comment: @Alvarez Entiendo que conceptualmente esta respuesta es correcta, el tema es el selector `$("a")` . Este código va a hacer que absolutamente todos los `<a>` de la página tomen ese comportamiento.  Mejor sería que utilices una clase para separar los elementos que quieres que tomen ese comportamiento, algo como `$("a.links")`